# hook_theme_registry_alter Why would Drupal forget that a module is registered?

Tags: 7, hooks

I am using a module that is using [hook_theme_registry_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7.x).  When I clear the cache it works fine the first time I load the page.  If I refresh the page Drupal forgets the module exists, and does not run the function to make the module work.

From the Drupal documentation I understand that:

> This hook is only executed as the theme cache is re-built. Changes here will not be visible until the next cache clear.

So it makes sense to me why it works immediately after a cache clear.  But, why does Drupal forget that the module exists on the following refresh?  Is this a Drupal problem or a problem with the module? What are some possible causes to investigate?

For further details, I am using is [Borealis RI](https://www.drupal.org/project/borealis#borealis_ri).  I have used it a dozen times in the past without this problem. The `hook_theme_registry_alter` function is called on line 124 http://cgit.drupalcode.org/borealis/tree/borealis_ri/borealis_ri.module